# WebLogic 12.2 + primefaces Critical error during deployment

Tags: jsf, primefaces, weblogic12c

I am have some projects using primefaces-4.0.jar primefaces-extensions-0.6.2.jar. In weblogic 12.1 the project runs ok but in weblogic 12.2 i got this error:

```
<23/05/2018 11h39min32s,SSS BRT> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
Source Document: zip:C:/wls1221301/user_projects/domains/domain2/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_auto_generated_ear_/ugrl40/war/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-extensions-0.6.2.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
Cause: Class 'org.primefaces.extensions.component.masterdetail.MasterDetailRenderer' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/primefaces/component/menuitem/MenuItem.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
Source Document: zip:C:/wls1221301/user_projects/domains/domain2/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_auto_generated_ear_/ugrl40/war/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-extensions-0.6.2.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
Cause: Class 'org.primefaces.extensions.component.masterdetail.MasterDetailRenderer' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/primefaces/component/menuitem/MenuItem
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:705)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
Source Document: zip:C:/wls1221301/user_projects/domains/domain2/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_auto_generated_ear_/ugrl40/war/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-extensions-0.6.2.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
Cause: Class 'org.primefaces.extensions.component.masterdetail.MasterDetailRenderer' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/primefaces/component/menuitem/MenuItem
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:364)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:288)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.RenderKitConfigProcessor.addRenderers(RenderKitConfigProcessor.java:313)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.RenderKitConfigProcessor.process(RenderKitConfigProcessor.java:179)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/primefaces/component/menuitem/MenuItem
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.classHasAnnotations(Util.java:1005)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationInstanceFactoryMetadataMap.onPut(ApplicationInstanceFactoryMetadataMap.java:75)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.component.menuitem.MenuItem
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:104)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<23/05/2018 11h39min32s,SSS BRT> <Error> <javax.faces> <BEA-000000> <O aplicativo não foi iniciado corretamente na inicialização. Não foi possível encontrar Fábrica: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. Attempting to find backup.> 
<23/05/2018 11h39min32s,SSS BRT> <Error> <javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config> <BEA-000000> <Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. 
at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:561)
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:283)
at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:140)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:343)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:706)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
[EL Warning]: 2018-05-23 11:39:32.403--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--No partition instance associated with current SessionManager instance.
<23/05/2018 11h39min32s,SSS BRT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "184243883603620" for task "2" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.component.menuitem.MenuItem"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.component.menuitem.MenuItem
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.component.menuitem.MenuItem
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:104)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Do you have any idea how we can fix this? 
There is any configuration on weblogic to solve the problem with the classload?

Comment: We are going to need more than this to help you. How did you add the dependency? What research have you done?

Comment: What is unclear about `Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.component.menuitem.MenuItem`?

Comment: Hi, the jar files are on /web-inf/lib.

Comment: In primefaces forum the extensions a developer said that the problem is on weblogic 12.2 classloader, but if I change the version of primefacfes extensions to 1.0 or higher  the class load ok. For me changing this library means that i need to rewrite all views

Comment: The solution that we need to use is migrate to a newer version of primefaces.